# Solidity receive

Tags: javascript, solidity, hardhat

Hi i creating 2 smart contract first allow users to bid house price and when price is set for example at 2 eth second contract provide receive function that should collect exacly the same amount of ether and send this ether to previous house owner.But idk what going wrong when i bid to 2 eth and when i try to receive 2 eth i have error(but when i change `require(amount==msg.value,"pay more");`  to this `require(amount<=msg.value,"pay more");`   everythink work but it should receive exacly the same amount of eth)
i adding code plx help me fix this

bid contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

contract list{

uint256   highestbid;
uint256  id;
address owner;
address winaddress;
mapping(uint256=>mapping(address=>uint256))public bidlist;

constructor(){
    owner=msg.sender;
}
modifier funds(){
require(msg.sender.balance>highestbid,"note enought funds");
_;

}

function bid(uint _bidamount)public  funds{
if(_bidamount>highestbid){
highestbid=_bidamount;
id++;
bidlist[id][owner]=_bidamount;

}else
revert("place highest bid");
}

function winneramount() public view returns(uint256){
return highestbid;
}
}
```

receive contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;
import "./realesatate.sol";

contract buying is list{

uint256 public amount;
constructor(){
amount=highestbid;
}
receive() payable external {
require(amount==msg.value,"pay more");   
}
}
```

I tried to change equal to <= and its seems work but this must work for equal amount of eth

Answer (score 0):

`buying.contructor()` only executes once the contract is deploy, and both `buying.amount` and `list.highestbid` are 0 at this point.

Then, when `list.bid()` function executed with 2ETH, `list.highestbid` is updated to 2ETH, but at the same time `buying.amount` is not updated, it is still 0. Thats why it works only when

```
require(amount <= msg.value, "pay more"); // amount = 0
```

- 

**Suggestion**: either you can directly compare `msg.value` with `highestbid`;

```
require(highestbid <= msg.value, "pay more");
```

or you should add a virtual function in `list` and override it in `buying`

```
// list
function _setHighestBid(uint256 val) internal virtual {
  highestBid = val;
}


// buying
function _setHighestBid(uint256 val) internal override {
  highestBid = val;
  amount = val;
}
```